# How to write all the SOAP response values into CSV file with delimiter in Groovy for SoapUI

Tags: xml, csv, groovy, soapui

I am new to Groovy and working on Soap UI. Currently I am working on Groovy module, where I need to write the all tag values with delimiter on to `.csv` file. The solution I got from other post is specific to `xpath`.

But am trying to achieve the below:

1. all the values of all the repetitive arrays to be stored in csv file
2. each array in single row with delimiter

**Expected Output:**

```
code;Name;Category;Manufacturer;Price;Stock // as header
1234;product name;some category;manufacturer;100;1
1235;product name2;some category2;manufacturer2;1002;2
```

XML sample:

```
<ns2:personalarray1Response>
    <ns2:personarray1>
        <Code>1234</Code>
        <Name>product name</Name>
        <Category>some category</Category>
        <Manufacturer>manufacturer</Manufacturer>
        <Price>100</Price>
        <Stock>1</Stock>
    </ns2:personarray1>
    <ns2:personarray1>
        <Code>1235</Code>
        <Name>product name2</Name>
        <Category>some category2</Category>
        <Manufacturer>manufacturer2</Manufacturer>
        <Price>1002</Price>
        <Stock>2</Stock>
    </ns2:personarray1>
    <ns2:personarray1>
        <Code>1234</Code>
        <Name>product name</Name>
        <Category>some category</Category>
        <Manufacturer>manufacturer</Manufacturer>
        <Price>100</Price>
        <Stock>1</Stock>
    </ns2:personalarray1>
</ns2:personalarray1Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `Script Assertion` for the same Soap Request step and need **not require** to use additional Groovy script step.

**Script**

```
 //Change file name as needed
def fileName = '/file/path/to.csv'
def delimiter = ',' 

assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def personalInfos = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'personarray1' }


//Create the list of data (person array) 
def list = personalInfos.collect {info -> info.children()*.name().collectEntries{[(it): info."$it"] } }


def sb = new StringBuffer(list[0].keySet().join(delimiter))
sb.append('\n')

list.collect { sb.append(it.values().join(delimiter)).append('\n')}
log.info "Data going to be written into file: \n ${sb.toString()}"

new File(fileName).write(sb.toString())
```

Comment: Thank you Rao for the code. But I want it in a groovy module as am creating a .csv file at runtime in the project path. I tried the above code, abut getting error as "wed Nov22 18:30.07 GMT+05:30 2017:ERROR:An erroro occured [could not find matching constructor for: java:io:file(java.io.file)], see error log for details"

Comment: in the SOAP Ui Log, the values are getting fetched and displayed. but the same is not getting write to the file. Also, my response file got created.

Comment: @SD31, you were either trying something wrong or not tried as it is provided in the solution.

Comment: @SD31, if you look at the error you posted in the comment, you are passing file object to file. If you have already file object, then just `file.write(sb.toString())`.

Comment: ERROR:An error occured [could not find matching constructor for: java:io:file(java.io.file)]
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for : java:io:file(java.io.file)
at groovy.lang.MetaclassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaclassImpl.java.1550)
at groovy.lang.MetaclassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaclassImpl.java.1404)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaclassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaclassConstructorSite.Java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.Java:57)

Comment: Hope you looked at the other comment explaining

Comment: Thanks Rao, am able to write the data into the files :D The Node values, which is returned in soap response as blank is not getting printed to the file.

Comment: @SD31, appreciate if you can accept it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) then.